# Android Wear: Card Scroll View Does Not Scroll

Tags: android, wear-os

I am today testing out the card scroll view but with all the examples I followed my one does not scroll and I am not sure why.

**card_scroll_view_test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <android.support.wearable.view.CardScrollView
        android:id="@+id/card_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_box="all">

        <android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="HELLO"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/big_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame>
    </android.support.wearable.view.CardScrollView>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

So this contains a card frame with a linear layout that holds two child text views. The last text view holds a really big string to test for scrolling

**WearActivity.java**

```
public class WearActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.card_scroll_view_test);
         setupCardScrollView();
    }

     private void setupCardScrollView(){
       CardScrollView cardScrollView =
       (CardScrollView) findViewById(R.id.card_scroll_view);
       cardScrollView.setExpansionEnabled(true);
       cardScrollView.setExpansionDirection(CardFrame.EXPAND_DOWN);
       cardScrollView.setCardGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    }
}
```

I also checked to see if the root box inset layout might have been the issue by making the CardScrollView the root view, but the problem persists.

Comment: same here. I hope they fix it in the next version of the sdk

Comment: @Blackbelt, so its a known bug with the wear SDK?

Comment: I don't know if it is a bug or an expected behavior. It is annoying for sure

Comment: @Blackbelt, I think it is because I followed the book example line by line and it does not work for me still

Comment: I agree with you. It looks like a bug but I didn't find anything on the android's bugtrack so I can't be 100% sure that is a bug. Imo we should wait until the sdk is stable

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work if you:

1. Remove BoxInsetLayout (CardScrollView become parent view)
2. Set setExpansionFactor on CardScrollView and set the properties on CardFrame as well.

Update to your code:

```
private void setupCardScrollView(){
    CardScrollView cardScrollView = 
         (CardScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_scroll_view);
    cardScrollView.setExpansionEnabled(true);
    cardScrollView.setExpansionDirection(1);
    cardScrollView.setExpansionFactor(10.0F);

    CardFrame cardFrame = (CardFrame) view.findViewById(R.id.card_frame);
    cardFrame.setExpansionEnabled(true);
    cardFrame.setExpansionDirection(1);
    cardFrame.setExpansionFactor(10.0F);

}
```